# Use of key, and .count in max function in Python

Tags: python, list

What is use of "key" in Python max function used on a list?

```py
lst = [1, 2, 7, 67, 2, 45, 6732, 52, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2]
print(max(lst,key=lst.count))
```

And, also what does lst.count does?

Comment: Run `lst.count()` in your terminal.  What does it appear to be doing?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Comment: What has your *research* shown as to the role of the `key` parameter?  Once read and researched; *then* ask a question regarding any remaining questions.  Please, do research *first*.

Comment: @S3DEV are .count() and .count the same?

Comment: What does your terminal and research tell you?  Tip: `.count` is a function of the `list` type.  `.count()` is a means by which to *call* the function; with the specified parameter.  `.count` is *not* called in the `max()` function statement as the function is called by the iterator (and then used) *inside* the `max()` function.

Comment: I consider `.count` and `.count()` to different. `.count` is a data member of class List, and `.count()` is a member function/method of class List

Comment: `.count` is a function of the `list` *type*, and `.count()` is that fuction being called.

Answer (score 1):

**key** is a function where the list is passed and comparison is performed based on its return value.

**lst.count** returns the occurrence count of each element in the list, and then max returns the list item with max occurrence, which is 2 for your list.

You can go through the doc link jonrsharpe provided for reference.